# Melt a array and make numeric values character

Tags: arrays, r, data.table, melt

I have a array and I want to melt it based on the dimnames. The problem is that the dimension names are large numeric values and therefore making them character would convert them to a wrong ID see the example:

```
test <- array(1:18, dim = c(3,3,2), dimnames = list(c(00901291282245454545454,329293929929292,2929992929922929),
                                                   c("a", "b", "c"),
                                                   c("d", "e")))

library(reshape2)
library(data.table)
test2 <- data.table(melt(test))
test2[, Var1 := as.character(Var1)]

> test2
Var1 Var2 Var3 value
1: 9.01291282245455e+20    a    d     1
2:      329293929929292    a    d     2
3:     2929992929922929    a    d     3
4: 9.01291282245455e+20    b    d     4
5:      329293929929292    b    d     5
6:     2929992929922929    b    d     6
7: 9.01291282245455e+20    c    d     7
8:      329293929929292    c    d     8
9:     2929992929922929    c    d     9
10: 9.01291282245455e+20    a    e    10
11:      329293929929292    a    e    11
12:     2929992929922929    a    e    12
13: 9.01291282245455e+20    b    e    13
14:      329293929929292    b    e    14
15:     2929992929922929    b    e    15
16: 9.01291282245455e+20    c    e    16
17:      329293929929292    c    e    17
18:     2929992929922929    c    e    18
```

How could I make the first column with the large IDs character? What I am currently doing is pasting a character letter to the dimnames and then melt, making it a character and then take a substring, which is really inefficient. It is important that it is an efficient solution because the dataset is millions  of rows. There are two problems,first the 0's are deleted if they are in front of the ID and it is converted to a e+20 character.

Comment: options(scipen=99) will resolve the e+20 issue

Comment: the 0's at the start will rip off if its a numeric column. I don't think we can avoid it. If you were importing data from csv files etc then specify this column as a character one there itself to avoid this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your dimnames as `character` and then slighly modify `melt.array` which is called when you do `melt` on your `array`:

```
test <- array(1:18, dim = c(3,3,2), dimnames = list(c("00901291282245454545454", "329293929929292", "2929992929922929"),
                                                    c("a", "b", "c"),
                                                    c("d", "e")))
```

Customise `melt.array` to add a parameter which permits to decide wether you want the conversion or not:

```
melt.array2 <- function (data, varnames = names(dimnames(data)), conv=TRUE, ...) 
{
    values <- as.vector(data)
    dn <- dimnames(data)
    if (is.null(dn)) 
        dn <- vector("list", length(dim(data)))
    dn_missing <- sapply(dn, is.null)
    dn[dn_missing] <- lapply(dim(data), function(x) 1:x)[dn_missing]
    if(conv){ # conv is the new parameter to know if conversion needs to be done
        char <- sapply(dn, is.character)
        dn[char] <- lapply(dn[char], type.convert)
    }
    indices <- do.call(expand.grid, dn)
    names(indices) <- varnames
    data.frame(indices, value = values)
}
```

Try the new function on your example (with `conv=FALSE`):

```
head(melt.array2(test, conv=FALSE))
                        # X1 X2 X3 value
# 1  00901291282245454545454  a  d     1
# 2          329293929929292  a  d     2
# 3         2929992929922929  a  d     3
# 4  00901291282245454545454  b  d     4
# 5          329293929929292  b  d     5
# 6         2929992929922929  b  d     6
```

**EDIT**

In the development version of `reshape2` (`devtools::install_github("hadley/reshape")`, `melt.array` is differently defined and you can use parameter `as.is` to avoid the conversion:

```
melt(test, as.is=TRUE)
```

will give you the same result as above (with `Var1` etc instead of `X1` etc).